# How to reduce the cache size in Windows 2008 Server R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a query regarding cache memory.

When I run my application, the number of page faults are increasing drastically, and many of them are hard page faults. So in order to reduce hard page faults I want to reduce cache size. But I am unable to find how I have to the required task.
How can I do this?

I have gone through many forums but couldn't get the help which I needed.
Is there any setting at the OS level to do this?

Comment: What cache are you talking about? What makes you think a page fault is something that needs to be fixed? What makes you think *decreasing* a cache will reduce page faults?

Answer (score 0):

Hard fault means that there is not enough memory, and Windows have to use the pagefile. There is nothing you can do about it (except fine-tuning the running services and applications, maybe optimize the code you running).

The only solution to stop hard faults is getting more memory (as far as I know... Besides the things I wrote.)

(Simple cache, as in "Standby" memory in Windows will be thrown out once anything needs it. It's like memory that is used, but can re-used any time without any delay. It's there, it's usable.)

Comment: I had the memory problem with a RAID array: File cache been growing and growing, eating up my memory. The solution was easy, the RAID had to be rebuilt. There is a tool that let's you chop down the file-cache, but it won't really help. It's not even a workaround.